# Problem calling a Composable function in an Observable

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a problem with this especial situation. How can I call a composable function after I received a result from Observer?

```
@Composable
fun ProfileScreen(
    onNavigate: () -> Unit,
    account: Account,
    viewModel: DBMovieViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
    lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current
) {
    viewModel.getListMovies()
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color.Black)
    ) {
        Column {
            ProfileComponent(account)
            viewModel.listMovies.observe(lifecycleOwner){
                MediaList(movies = it) -> Here is the problem, I can't call a Composable function in an Observable
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use it like this:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun ProfileScreen(
    onNavigate: () -> Unit,
    account: Account,
    viewModel: DBMovieViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
    val listMovies by viewModel.listMovies.collectAsState(initial = emptyList())
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color.Black)
    ) {
        Column {
            ProfileComponent(account)
            MediaList(movies = listMovies)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: from where to get that collectAsState function?? what is it exactly?? i beginner to compose...

Comment: You can find the docs [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/package-summary#(kotlinx.coroutines.flow.StateFlow).collectAsState(kotlin.coroutines.CoroutineContext)).